# "Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain" when running an app in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am seeing this error happening intermittently on a small pretty simple scala project in version 2016.1.

I have tried rebuilding project, shutting down intellij and restarting. They do not seem to help.

Anyone have experience with this and/or a a workaround?

Comment: I have the same issue, but with java instead of scala.